# Drag and resize columns with direction rtl not working in MUI-Datatables

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

Drag and resize columns of MUI-Datatables with direction rtl not working when the material-ui theme direction is set to 'rtl'. Any Solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is an open issue on their GitHub:
https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/issues/1524

It appears that this isn't supported, but there is a workaround:

> Ah, I see. This is because the position of the select column is assumed to be on the left when the calculations are done. This isn't supported at the moment.
>
> A workaround would be to create a column that existed on the far right that was check boxes that acted similarly to the select column.

Comment: I couldn't get anything from those two lines